# Search is actually working but returning more than 1 value

Tags: php

I am searching for at least one data inside the database. Also I want to see all the data with the same name returning inside the database. But when I search just one data, its always returning all the data inside the database.

Here is the code of "search" that I am doing:

```
// $_POST['search'] is for the button
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
 // $_GET['prodName'] column name in the database
 $search = isset($_GET['prodName']);
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM `newitem` WHERE `prodName` = '$search'";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
 if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   echo "result found";
  }
 } else {
  echo "result not found";
 }
}
```

And this is for the HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="" class="form-horizontal">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="search" class="control-label col-md-2">Search</label>
  <div class="col-md-8">
   <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="Search Product Name">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
   <input type="submit" name="search" class="btn btn-info" value="SEARCH">
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

I also try this:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) => 1)
```

it has an error that says:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW) in C:\wamp\www\OrderingSystem\account.php on line 142
```

Please help me for this one.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: use limit 1 in your query to get a single result

Comment: You can use LIMIT 1.

Comment: this is failing you `isset($_GET['prodName']);`

Comment: then this `if(mysqli_num_rows($result) => 1)` symbols are reversed.

Comment: @Fred-ii- didn't you read? *Search is actually working*, so how can it be?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM \`newitem\` WHERE \`prodName\` = 'TRUE'` works well for you?

Comment: @AlanMachado Sorry, I'm up in the clouds with [this guy.........](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NWzROoxS2b4)

Comment: Change the `=>` test to `>=` in `if(mysqli_num_rows($result) => 1)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *I also try this:*
>   *`if(mysqli_num_rows($result) => 1)`*

`=>` is the separator for associative arrays, which is why you are presently getting that parse error.

What you may have meant to use is `>=` or just plain `>` as in "higher than or equal to" or "higher than".

Then this will fail you, since it will always be considered as being "set".

```
$search = isset($_GET['prodName']);
```

Change it to:

```
$search = $_GET['prodName'];
```

Or you may have meant to use it as a [**ternary operator**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

For example:

```
$var = !empty($_GET['var']) ? $_GET['var'] : "";
```

Plus, your code is open to SQL injection. Use a prepared statement.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

Other reference(s):

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

---

Your code may contain syntax errors. 
Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code.

Check for errors against `$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);`.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.